# Will i replace the MPLS cloud as a "P" router?

Tags: vpn, mpls

I'm following along with a MPLS problem. I have this topology...

[image: MPLS Diagram]

R1 is to reach R6 via an MPLS VPN and states that the MPLS cloud is to be configured with OSPF.

All I want to know is, am i right in saying...

R1, R4, R6 and R7 will be the CE routers.

R2, R3 and R5 will be the PE routers.

When implementing this, the "mpls cloud" as shown in the diagram, will be replaced with a "P" router?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking "can I replace the cloud with one P router as a lab exercise?" The answer is yes.

Comment: Would using just one be enough?or should i add more? If in the case there were between 25 - 300 users running off of each switch

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to simulate or test.